# How can I generate similar users recommendation from data of this format?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, data-science

I'm trying to generate similar user recommendations for a website. Data consists of 'user_id', 'category' and 'no_of_visits_to_a_category'.

```
user_id cat_1 cat-2 .................cat_3
1       2      5                      6
2       5      4                      5
.
.
10      3      7                      5
```

Where values in the matrix describes the number of visit to each category.
How do I generate similarity between users?

Comment: There are many ways. This is a good book that will allow you to code it yourself: https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications-ebook/dp/B00F8QDZWG/ref=sr_1_4?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1472216069&sr=1-4&keywords=python+artificial+intelligence#nav-subnav

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like this is your first question. Please read this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this will help you to understand how to post questions more effectively.

Comment: This is a classic example of recommender systems. Here are some useful links: (http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/16_Recommender_Systems.html), (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saXRzxgFN0o&index=1&list=PL_npY1DYXHPT-3dorG7Em6d18P4JRFDvH), (http://online.cambridgecoding.com/notebooks/eWReNYcAfB/implementing-your-own-recommender-systems-in-python-2), (https://www.quora.com/Which-algorithms-are-used-in-recommender-systems), (http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/)